# Prevent running out of memory in C# when running math simulations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, out-of-memory

My project simulates the economy of a game by running 10s of millions of sims using C# in Unity. Every run, I track the economy using the Stat class

```
public class Stat
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<double> SampleSpace { get; private set; }

    public Stat(string _name = "")
    {
        Name = _name;
        SampleSpace = new List<double> { };
    }    
    public void AddToSampleSpace(double _sample) { SampleSpace.Add(_sample); }    
}
```

So, every time certain game events occur, I expand the SampleSpace of a Stat instance by adding a double. However, when I try to run larger sims (1 billion for example), I get "OutOfMemoryException Out Of Memory." What is a better way to implement this and prevent running out of memory?

Note that I already run this application as 64-bit Windows, and I'm not running parallel processes. I also have dozens of instances of the Stat class during sims. I want to preserve the full history of how much a player has bet, has won, whether they increased/lowered their bet, etc.

Comment: do you need all the history? It's not very clear what kind of sim you are running, can you can get by just by holding the state of 1 previous iteration? And if you need the history maybe compact it by averaging over periods of time.

Comment: @bolov yes, I need all the history. I use the data to do statistical analysis. It's simulating gambling, so I want the history of how much a player has bet, has won, whether they increased/lowered their bet, etc.

Comment: That really sounds like a case for a database (or something similar) - you simply cannot store that much data in memory, you need to store it on disk

Comment: But do you need all the stats/history in memory?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace yes, I need all the history in memory. I currently have the project save it all in an .csv file after the sims are finished.

Comment: Do the sims run concurrently, or one after the other? If they run concurrently, how many can concurrently, and how large is the size of the private unshared data for each sim? (I am not asking about the stats)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I have not calculated that, but since I like to run sims in powers of 10, I know I can run 100 million sims with no issues. The memory exceptions appear once I try to run over about 300 million sims, so I empirically find it reasonable to aim for 1 billion successful sims.

Comment: Try to figure that out. Lets just speculatively assume each sim uses 256 bytes of unshared private data, and 300mio concurrent sims are at play, we are already looking at 300mio x 256 = 77 GB of memory you just need for the sims alone. And that's without stats. Even if each sim only uses 64 bytes (that's 8 Doubles or Int64's), we are still looking at 300mio x 64 = 19 GB of memory needs for the sims alone. Acceptable perhaps on a machine with 64 GB RAM or more, but can become a concern on a machine with only 32 GB of RAM as there would then only be about 10 GB left for the stats.

Comment: And then there is the overhead for each object instance you create. Object overhead on 64-bit .NET is 16 bytes. If every sim is just comprised of only a single object instance specific to that sim, the object overhead alone for 300mio sims is 300mio x 16 = 4.8 GB. (Technically, an object cannot be smaller than 24 bytes on 64-bit .NET. But eight of those 24 bytes are available to store object data, so if your object contains at least a Double or for example two Int32's, the effective overhead is just 16 bytes)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace then perhaps my solution should be to simply aggregate my stats so it's stored in a ulong instead of a List<double> for larger sims, and keep doing my more complex analyses on smaller sims.

Comment: Use a **database** to store information rather than trying to keep everything in memory when you don't need to.